# Python: Compare lists and create arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have two lists of lists (Python) and I am looking for the **fastest** way to compare the two lists (of lists) and create an array (with two columns). For example, the two lists (**A** and **B**) can be like this:

```
A = [[0, 1, 3, 6], [3, 7], [0, 1, 2], [3]]
B = [[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3]]
```

Lists A and B always have the same exact shape. After comparison, I would like the ensuing array (say **C**) to take corresponding elements of A and B and form an array of pairs (first element from A and second element of B). For example, here C would be

```
C = np.array( [ [0,0], [1,0], [3,0], [6,0], [3,1], [7,1], [0,2], [1,2]
        [2,2], [3,3] ] )
```

If possible, I would also like to remove self pairs (like [0,0] and [2,2] ).

Presently, I am implementing it in the form of a list (that is not very fast when I have to **deal with huge datasets with millions of rows**). Here is the code for creation of lists that I am presently using:

```
C_list = map(lambda x, y : zip(x,y), A, B)
C_list = [item for sublist in C_list for item in sublist]
```

And, to remove self pairs, I am using the following snippet:

```
C_list = [(x, y) for x, y in C_list if x != y]
```

I am looking for a fast way to implement this and I will really appreciate any help.

Comment: Looks like the cleanest pure Python code for that would be `C_list = [item for item in zip((a for l in A for a in l), (b for l in B for b in l)) if item != item[::-1]]`, but it looks like that takes 15% longer than what you have after adding the filter you want, and it would almost certainly be faster with Numpy methods, if possible (I'm pretty sure there's a `flatten()`, for instance).

Comment: using `numpy` will tricky because the data is inhomogeneous

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is going to be slower than necessary because you are materializing the huge lists several times to do your data transformations. You should set this up using lazy constructs. On Python 2, you have to replace `map` with `itertools.imap` and `zip` with `itertools.izip`. Keeping that in mind, here is a Python 3 approach that I think should be faster, because you make one pass using `np.fromiter` to materialize an array directly from an a lazy iterator, <s>using the `count` argument to pre-allocate the array instead of resizing on-demand</s> **EDIT** Actually, you can't use `count` because you won't know ahead of time how many items you filter out, stupid mistake on my part:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> zipped = zip(itertools.chain.from_iterable(A), itertools.chain.from_iterable(B))
>>> it = (e for t in zipped if t[0] != t[1] for e in t)
>>> arr = np.fromiter(it,  dtype=int).reshape(-1, 2)
>>> arr
array([[1, 0],
       [3, 0],
       [6, 0],
       [3, 1],
       [7, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 2]])
>>>
```

At the very least, this will be *much* more memory efficient.

Comment: @SiddTheKid so, I gather this *was* actually when you tried it on your data?

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer! Is there a mistake in the code, because arr should also contain the pairs [0,2] and [1,2] in addition to the ones that it already contains? It will be useful if I can know of two separate techniques (one where it keeps the self pairs and second where it removes the self pairs. On a side note, it does make the code more memory efficient. =)

Comment: If one passes count*2, while having " it = (e for t in zipped for e in t) " followed by " arr = np.fromiter(it, count=2*count, dtype=int).reshape(-1, 2) " then there is no error, but one gets all pairs including self pairs. How can one use this and remove the self pairs? I get error (iterator too short) when I use "it = (e for t in zipped if t[0] != t[1] for e in t)" followed by " arr = np.fromiter(it, count=2*count, dtype=int).reshape(-1, 2) " . I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @SiddTheKid yeah just figured it out, editing the answer. Unfortunately, you can't use `count`

Comment: @  juanpa.arrivillaga : I figured. So, is there a way to tackle this problem (while removing self pairs)? Using a modification of your method I was able to solve another problem (speed the code while having self pairs). =)